# Как сохранить путь к файлу в Extract Constant?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Extract Constant есть во всех прогармма IntelJIDEA, Android Studio. php storm.. суть в том что в поле Extract to class мне приходиться каждый раз указывать другой класс для хранения Констант. Можно ли как то автоматизировать этот процесс и сохранить  путь.

По умолчанию путь указывает в текущем классе где вызывается это окно.

Я бы хотел чтобы константы сохранялись в отдельном файле.Если конечно есть такой способ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишите в техподдержку: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

---

Можно сначала ответ здесь поискать: [JetBrains support](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/) ★ [Community support](https://www.jetbrains.com/support/community/#section=communities)